# How can I force the user to register/login first before being redirected back to the current URL?

Tags: 8, users, forms

I'm displaying a form using the Form API under a given URL. User gets this URL and accesses it. But before the user fills out the form, they need to be registered or logged in.

How can I send the user to the login page, or present the login form, then subsequently direct them back to the form under the given URL?

This is not a Webform -- I'm using the Form API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect to the login page and provide a destination query parameter to the current route to redirect back after login:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($this->currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
      return $this->redirect(
          'user.login',
          [],
          ['query' => ['destination' => Url::fromRoute('<current>')->toString()]]
      );
    }

    // build form

    return $form
  }
```

Don't forget to add a `use Drupal\Core\Url;` statement to the class.